# Comparing Strings in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

The following code is comparing two strings. It increments the counter if there is C found in the `Input`. I want to know where is problem in my code. Its not giving the output.

```
.data
Input: .asciiz "\nThis is Lab-05 of the course CSCS323 Computer Organization and Assembly Language.We are FCCU/CS Students"
Check: .asciiz "C"
Result: .asciiz "\nThe number of times this character occurs in the string is: "
.text
.globl main
 main:

 la $t0, Input #load address of input
 la $t1, Check #load address of Check
 li $s1, 0     #Set Counter to zero

compare:
lb $t2, 0($t0)
lb $t3, 0($t1)

beq $t2, $t3, counter
addi $t0, $t0, 1

counter:
addi $s1, $s1, 1
jr $ra

add $a0 , $s1 , $zero
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s1
syscall
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger to see what's actually happening?  Single-stepping your code often catches problems.

Answer (score 1):

The `jr` instruction is wrong.  You are returning from your subroutine there.  You want `j compare`

`lb $t3,0($t1)` is invariant across the loop (e.g. you increment `$t0` but not `$t1`), so you can move the instruction before `compare:`

You don't exit your compare loop at the end of the scan of `Input`.  That is, after `lb $t2,0($t0)`.  You need to compare $t2 against zero

You don't increment `$t0` if you branch to `counter:`.  This means you will loop infinitely [with the `jr` fixed].

You don't use the `Result` string

Here's the corrected code.  It may not be perfect, but it's closer [Please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
.data
Input: .asciiz "\nThis is Lab-05 of the course CSCS323 Computer Organization and Assembly Language.We are FCCU/CS Students"
Check: .asciiz "C"
Result: .asciiz "\nThe number of times this character occurs in the string is: "

.text
.globl main
main:
    # output the result string
    li      $v0,4               # print_string syscall number
    la      $a0,Result          # string address
    syscall

    la      $t0,Input           # load address of Input
    li      $s1,0               # Set Counter to zero

    la      $t1,Check           # load address of Check
    lb      $t3,0($t1)          # get "check" char value

    li      $s2,0               # get end of string (EOS) char

compare:
    lb      $t2,0($t0)          # get next char in 'Input'
    addi    $t0,$t0,1           # advance pointer to next char

    beq     $t2,$s2,done        # is current char 0?  if yes, fly and print

    bne     $t2,$t3,compare     # does current match check? If no, loop
    addi    $s1,$s1,1           # yes, increment count
    b       compare             # loop

done:
    li      $v0,1               # print_int syscall
    move    $a0,$s1             # get total count to correct register
    syscall
```